# How to pass a static parameter to a typeprovider in f# inside a function

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I'm using the `FSharp.Data typeproviders`.

I would like to make a function that has a parameter that sets the `typeprovider's` sample string or file location.

```
let SyncIt url sample converter storer =
    async {
        url
        |> MakeRequestAsync 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> JsonProvider< sample >.Parse
        |> Seq.iter (converter >> storer)
    }
```

If a call the JsonProvider in the module with

```
[<Literal>]
let sample = """{"name":"Peter","age":9}"""

type provider = JsonProvider<sample>
```

works fine. Why can't I pass it as a `parameter`? I know it has something to do with the reference being clear at compile time, but cannot figure out how to get around it other than declaring each `providers explicitly`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function cannot take a value of static parameter as an argument, because the value has to be determined at compile time. This means that if you write:

```
let [<Literal>] sample = """{"name":"Peter","age":9}"""
let parseHtml html = JsonProvider<sample>.Parse(html)
```

... everything is fine, because the compiler knows that `sample` is a constant (and the compiler knows its value) and so it can instantiate the type provider (during compilation) to generate types. If you write something like:

```
let parseHtml sample html = JsonProvider<sample>.Parse(html)
```

... then the compiler cannot know what the value of `sample` may be at runtime and so it cannot generate the required types at compile time. Type providers do not "exist" at runtime, so the types cannot be generated on the fly (This would not be really useful, because the point of type providers is to give you some compile-time safety guarantees).

**Your example.** In your case, it might make sense to take the specific `JsonProvider<sample>.Parse` function as an argument instead:

```
let SyncIt url parse storer =
    async {
        url
        |> MakeRequestAsync 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> parse
        |> Seq.iter (converter >> storer)
    }
```

This way, the caller can specify the static parameter to a type provider and then call your function to do the synchronization:

```
let [<Literal>] sample = """{"name":"Peter","age":9}"""
SyncIt url (JsonProvider<sample>.Parse) storer
```

Although, it is not entirely clear to me why you need a type provider here. The point of providers is to give you nice types that you can use to access a concrete source of data. If your `converter` and `storer` work on *any* JSON data file, then you might be able to get the thing done using just [JSON parser (also in F# Data)](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html).

**Asynchronous block.** Also, note that your code is not really running asynchronously - to make it asynchronous, you need to download the URL using `let!` operation:

```
let SyncIt url parser storer =
    async {
        let wc = new WebClient() 
        let! html = wc.AsyncDownloadString(url)
        parser html
        |> Seq.iter (converter >> storer)
    }
```

Comment: I added some more details. I did not fully understand why you need to use type providers if your `converter` and `storer` can (apparently) work on any JSON - so they do not benefit from the statically known types..

Comment: I'm in my second week of f# and starting to get to grips with some of the concepts. I use the typeprovider, because I like that most value types have been recognised. The converter maps from DomainTypes.Entity to a record type I defined. This record is stored in Redis. In trying to write a converter the fact that I cannot have more than one return type catches me out. Thanks for explaining. Regs, Remko